# Does PowerShell store a temporary copy of an imported module?

Tags: powershell

PS 5.1 on Win10 1709.

It's a sad, unimportant story, but I managed to overwrite the newest source to a script PowerShell module I was modifying. But my open PS session has the newest version imported; I can see the added commands, etc. It just no longer agrees with the version of the source that's on disk, i.e. in `c:\Program Files\WindowsPowershell\Modules\<modulename>`.

My question is when a module is imported, does PowerShell store the session version of the loaded module somewhere? Is it just in memory (in which case I'm out-of-luck), or is in a tmp directory somewhere?

IOW, if `c:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\testmod\1.0` contained the module source, and I do a `import-module testmod`, and then delete that testmod directory, the PS session can still use testmod, all of its commands, etc. Is the version it imported stored in some secret place temporarily, or is it just in memory?

The reason I even ask (I assumed it was gone and I'd just have to redo it) is that I opened *another* PS session and did a `get-module -ListAvailable`. Interestingly, to me anyway, that shows the new version of my module, i.e. shows the new commands. However, when I actually import the module in that session, it's the old version (as I would expect), with only the old commands available.

If the `-ListAvailable` only showed the old commands, I would assume it's gone and just start re-writing. But the fact that `-ListAvailable` is showing the new commands, and the fact that the other session still has all the new functionality available, made me decide to ask just on the off chance it copied the current version of the source to some hidden tmp location.

**Update:** @EBGreen indicated in a comment the majority of the answer; for exported commands/functions, .Definition works even if the original source is no longer available, e.g.

`(Get-Module <modulename>).Definition`.

But through some more digging around online I also found the means to see the source for unexported functions.

`$module.invoke( { (get-item function:<fcnname>).definition } )`

Comment: There is a function: (dir function:) drive you can see your loaded functions in.  You might check there to see if the behavior reflects the imported module.

Comment: Check whenever "previous versions" for that folder is activated on that machine or consider using a management system like git in the future for such cases.

Comment: You can probably see some of your code by using Get-Command to get the commands that your module exports then looking at the definition of each one

Comment: Thanks @EBGreen, the "looking at the definition" was the clue I needed!